# Why is facebook not using default Android openssl for logging in

Tags: android, facebook, security, ssl, openssl

These days I do some tests about using OpenSSL in android platforms. And I modified some openssl code to log the plain text which android apps send to SSL using SSL_write API. When I test apps like amazon and linkedin, I do find the login information(including username and password) in my log file. But in some other apps like facebook, I find there is no login information in log. But th log information also shows that facebook will use openssl to do some communication to its server.

So I just wonder, why is facebook not using default android openssl for login, how facebook protect users' sensitive information in login if it doesn't use openssl?

Comment: Did you clear your web cache before performing your experiment? You might have a preexisting credential, like a cookie, that is used in its stead. They could also be doing it in Javascript with something like WebSockets.

Comment: @jww yes,I'm sure this is not a problem about cache like cookies. Actually, I can get  plain texts of passwords and usernames in SSL when I log in facebook using the default browser in android. But using facebook's app, no useful information are logged in my log files. Anyway, thanks for your help!